# One can revoke access from itself in chat rooms

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Once I've accidently selected *no special access* for myself in a room I was owner of, and it worked. This should definitely be fixed to prevent future accidents. Or is this a **feature**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, nobody forces you to take the room owner duties in a room.

And it's not like your "accident" is such a tragedy – if you *really* did this unintentionally (which I have a hard time believing), it's not that hard to get another owner or a moderator to re-add you.